# Get a stream of permissions from a future

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to stream two types of location package based data:

```
final _location = Location();

runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       StreamProvider<PermissionStatus>(create: (_) => _location.hasPermission().asStream()),
       StreamProvider<bool>(create: (_) => _location.serviceEnabled().asStream()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp();
    )
)
```

When I 'stream' the data, it loads the initial value and streams that. It is not continuously listening to changes which is what I want to do. I have tried abstracting both futures into their own class and creating an async* stream that yields the current status, both of which give the same problem.

My use case involves continuously listening to the permission status and location on/off and shut down certain parts of the UI when these are modified in between tasks.

Simplified usage:

```
class LocationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer2<PermissionStatus, bool>(
        builder: (_, permission, isLocationEnabled, __) => _LocationWidget(
            permission: permission, isLocationEnabled: isLocationEnabled));
  }
}

class _LocationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _LocationWidget({this.permission, this.isLocationEnabled})
      : assert(permission != null);

  final PermissionStatus permission;
  final bool isLocationEnabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: (() {
      if (!isLocationEnabled)    // Check Bool and show different text
        return Text(
          "Off",
        );
      else
        return Text("On");
    }())));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ikerfah is right, you're creating a Stream from a Future, meaning the Stream will only contain a single event when the Future is completed (basically, it's not a real "stream" in the true sense of the word).

FutureBuilder won't work either, since the Future only gets completed once, so it will only trigger a single state change too.

If [this is the plugin you're using](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/501), it seems the author hasn't implemented anything to expose a "real" Stream for permission change events. I wouldn't hold my breath for that either, because as far as I know neither iOS nor Android broadcast an event if/when permissions are changed.

If you need to disable/enable something based on whether permissions have changed, you'll just need to set a periodic Timer in a StatefulWidget to poll for changes.

```
class _LocationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LocationWidgetState();
  }
}

class _LocationWidgetState extends State<_LocationWidget> {

  PermissionStatus permission;
  bool isLocationEnabled = false;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
     _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:5), (_) {
       var permission = await _location.hasPermission();
       var isLocationEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
       if(permission != this.permission || isLocationEnabled != this.isLocationEnabled)
           setState(() {});
     });  
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
     _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: (() {
      if (!isLocationEnabled)    // Check Bool and show different text
        return Text(
          "Off",
        );
      else
        return Text("On");
    }())));
  }
```

It's up to you whether 5 seconds is an appropriate interval. initState() should probably also set the initial isLocationEnabled/permission values when the state is initialized, too, rather than waiting 5 seconds for the timer to kick in.

Comment: This is the best way then, even if not ideal. And I've seen other libraries implementing the permissions stream in flutter reactive ble library, but couldn't quite figure out how to implement in my own. They only detect if the bluetooth + location is available instead of individual permissions for both, which I need.

Answer (score 3):

Add `updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true` to your `StreamProvider`

> By default, StreamProvider considers that the Stream listened uses immutable data. As such, it will not rebuild dependents if the previous and the new value are ==. To change this behavior, pass a custom updateShouldNotify.

Comment: Hey mate, this is not updating real-time in the UI. I tried using updateShouldNotify, and then switched the location off and on again, which does not show the updates in the UI. It is still only updating when the build function of the UI is called.

Comment: Switching on/off you mean the permission right ?

Comment: No, the bool value, which is on/off => true/false

Comment: Show me the code please where are you using this boolean

Comment: Whee are toggling the boolean please ?

Comment: _location.serviceEnabled() returns a bool which I want to stream. The trigger is being done by the future. Have marked in the code too

Comment: The library you are using, ```serviceEnabled``` return the result once only, to keep listen to the data you have to use ```onLocationChanged```

Comment: onLocationChanged streams the current location data (latitude, longitude), and not the permission status or location on/off.

Comment: Yes, as I told you the Library is giving only one time result , as you may notice it gives ```Future``` and not ```stream```, using ```asStream``` will just trigger it once.

Comment: If streams have to explicitly stated as 'Stream' then what's the purpose of converting a 'Future' to asStream() if it just streams the value once? And if not like this, how would anyone stream the serviceEnabled? No library seems to have implemented this

Comment: Because imagine you have a component that accept ```Stream``` as ```parameter```, and now you have a function from external library returns ```Future``` instead, you are not going to create another component just to pass the ```Future``` , and if you check the documentation, ```asStream(): The stream will produce single data or error event containing the completion result of this future, and then it will close with a done event.```

Comment: So basically, there is nothing that can actively convert a future to a listenable stream? Do you know any library which works with permission streams?

Comment: I used ```geolocator``` library , It has two function you may need ```Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled()``` and  ```Geolocator.checkPermission()```, try to wrap your widget with ```FutureBuilder```, this will rebuild your widget and check the permission when ```setState``` is called

Comment: The same thing can be done with the Location library. I've tried it... My app is IOT based so not having location permissions should reroute the user to the base screen. I've seen different libraries use location permission and status as a stream, but it is difficult to abstract them out into separate classes. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe checking your permissions in didChangeApplifecycle would do the job, As the user most certainly had to put the app in the background to change the permissions

Example

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  final loc = Location();
  final isPermitted = await loc.hasPermission();
  final isServiceEnabled = await loc.serviceEnabled()
  // request permissions
}
```